# UMD header with optional dependencies

Tags: javascript, amd

I'm in the situation of having an optional dependency within my library which I'd like to import through an UMD/AMD header, just like:

```
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof exports === "object") {
    module.exports = factory(require('proj4'));
  } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(['proj4'], factory);
  } else {
    root.ol = factory(root.proj4);
  }
}(this, function(proj4) {
   ...
   // proj4 is an "optional" dependency, just like a plugin
   if('function' === typeof proj4){
      // use proj4 within here
   }
});
```

The problem with this definition above is that this won't work when `proj4` is not available, which is a totally valid case. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here...is there any "standard" solution on how to handle such a scenario??

I mean...I guess what I could do is to..

```
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof exports === "object") {
    module.exports = factory();
  } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define([], factory);
  } else {
    root.ol = factory();
  }
}(this, function() {
  var proj4 = null;

  try {
     proj4 = require('proj4');
  } catch(e) {
    // loading failed      
  }

   ...
   // proj4 is an "optional" dependency, just like a plugin
   if('function' === typeof proj4){
      // use proj4 within here
   }
});
```

Is this the path to follow or is there any better solution??

Thx